# Camera function in background service

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I need to access device camera from android background service.I am getting this error "Fail to connect to camera service".Can anybody help in this regards

Here is my ImageGrab function

```
    void grapImage() {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    //mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    };
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
    mCamera.unlock();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Altaf

Comment: I have no experience with it. But I doubt that this is possible with the public APIs. That would open the door for apps to be recording video without the users knowledge. Which seems like a pretty big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder. I don't believe this can be done from a Service. Make sure you have the right permissions enabled in the Manifest and follow the procedures laid out in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html). That tells you exactly how to work with the camera. It states that you must start a preview before you can take a picture. Again, not sure if this is possible from a service but you might be able to find a "hack" or work around using the link provided.